# Paypal DoDirectPayment: Live transaction failed

Tags: asp-classic, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated paypal in my application using NVP call in ASP. i used sandbox accounts to test the paypal. it worked perfectly. but when it comes to live account  its showing the error

"This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration."

i used the following method to send data

```
nvpstr  =   "&PAYMENTACTION=Sale" & _
                        "&AMT="&Amount&"" &_
                        "&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa" &_
                        "&ACCT="&CardNumber&"" & _
                        "&EXPDATE="&ExpDate&""  &_
                        "&CVV2="&cvv&"" &_
                        "&FIRSTNAME="&firstname&"" &_
                        "&LASTNAME="&lastname&"" &_
                        "&STREET="&address1&"" &_
                        "&CITY="&city&"" &_
                        "&STATE="&state&"" &_
                        "&ZIP="&zip&"" &_
                        "&COUNTRYCODE=US" &_
                        "&CURRENCYCODE=USD" & _
                        "&IPADDRESS=192.168.1.77"
```

though i have used the correct live credentials and url its showing the same error. My account is paypal business account. is business and paypal pro account are same? am i missing some thing else?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you do not have Website Payments Pro enabled on your business account.  A business account does not mean that you have Website Payments Pro enabled, you have to sign up for this service.  You can contact PayPal customer support for assistance in signing up for this, or you can sign up through [here](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro).